# Getting error while npm install - request to https://registry.npmjs.org/axios failed

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I am trying to Learn  socket.io and React and hence i found a project [here](https://github.com/antoinfive/react-chat/)

One this to note is that I am just giving an example of a link. I tried to find more such projects on github and I am getting the same error as described below. So this error is not specific to this link but something related to npm or my system.

when I am trying to run

> npm install

it shows this error

```
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/axios failed, reason: write EPROTO 139829807306560:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:797:
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/abhi/.npm/_logs/2017-10-19T10_20_30_486Z-debug.log
abhi@abhi-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/react-chat$ npm config set strict-ssl falseabhi@abhi-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/react-chat$ npm install
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/axios failed, reason: write EPROTO 140309084555072:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:797:
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/abhi/.npm/_logs/2017-10-19T10_22_15_980Z-debug.log
abhi@abhi-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/react-chat$ npm install
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/axios failed, reason: write EPROTO 139873739618112:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:797:
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/abhi/.npm/_logs/2017-10-19T10_24_36_169Z-debug.log
```

some output

```
npm -v
5.0.3

node -v
v8.1.0

> npm config list

; cli configs
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/5.0.3 node/v8.1.0 linux x64"

; userconfig /home/abhi/.npmrc
strict-ssl = false

; node bin location = /home/abhi/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.0/bin/node
; cwd = /home/abhi/Desktop/react-chat
; HOME = /home/abhi
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

env | grep -i proxy

http_proxy=http://172.16.1.12:3128/
https_proxy=https://172.16.1.12:3128/
```

Comment: Hello, are you working behind a proxy ?

Comment: Yes! I think so. I added a code snippet. Have a look. @MickaëlB

Comment: @MickaëlB Thanks. I fixed this. I unset the proxy and it 's working :)